# Choosing sets with a few properties from a given set of elements

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Fix $n$ and $k$ with $n \geq 2k+1$. Let $X$ be an $n$ element set. Let $\binom{X}{k}$ denote the collection of $k$-element subsets of $X$. Suppose that $\mathcal{Y} \subseteq \binom{X}{k}$ is a family of $k$-element subsets of $X$ for which:

> for all distinct $A,B,C,D \in \mathcal{Y}$, if $A\cap B = \varnothing$ and $C\cap D = \varnothing$ then $|A\cap C|+|B\cap D| \leq k$.

**Question**: What is the largest size possible of such a family of $k$-subsets $\mathcal{Y}$? Is it possible for $\mathcal{Y}$ to have $\frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{k}$ (of the total $\binom{n}{k}$) $k$-subsets in it?

The problem is related to certain version of fractionally bicoloring two disjoint copies of Kneser graphs. The version of fractional bicoloring is this: If we have a two edge colored graph $G$, we properly color the vertices with the color function $C$, along with the additional condition that if we have two edges $(u,v)$ and $(x,y)$ of different colors in a graph $G$, then $|C(u)\cap C(x)|+|C(v)\cap C(y)|\le k$, where $k$ is the value such that $\frac{n}{k}$ is minimized, which is the fractional chromatic number.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming $k \geq 3$ is fixed and $n$ is large, every family of $k$-sets with the required property has at most $O(n^{k-1})$ sets. This answers in the negative the second question of the OP (at least for large $n$).

To see this, let $k \geq 3$ be fixed and $n$ large.
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of $k$-sets of $[n]$ with at least $4 n^{k-1}$ many sets. Let us prove that it cannot satisfy the property. By pigeonhole, one can find a set of $k-1$ elements which is contained in at least two different sets of $\mathcal{F}$, which we call $A$ and $C$.
Now remove all sets from $\mathcal{F}$ that intersect $A \cup C$.
Since $|A \cup C| = k+1$ and each vertex of $A \cup C$ is contained in at most $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ sets of $\mathcal{F}$, this deletes at most $(k+1)\binom{n-1}{k-1} \leq 2 n^{k-1}$ sets from $\mathcal{F}$. We are still left with at least $2 n^{k-1}$ sets in $\mathcal{F}$ and again by pigeonhole we can find two $k$-sets $B, D$ in $\mathcal{F}$, both disjoint from $A \cup C$, which intersect in at least two vertices. Then $A, B, C, D$ are distinct $k$-sets in $\mathcal{F}$, $A, B$ are disjoint, $C, D$ are disjoint, and $|A \cap C| + |B \cap D| \geq (k-1)+ 2 > k$, which proves that $\mathcal{F}$ does not satisfy the property.

Also, the family of $k$-sets of $[n]$ consisting of all the sets which contain $1$ has $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ many sets and satisfies the property (vacuously, because there is no pair of disjoint $k$-sets). This proves that $\Theta(n^{k-1})$ is the correct order of magnitude here.